# Why Bootstrap's Glyphicons sized at 24px are rendered as 26px height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm doing 'pixel shifting' in my css and after struggling for some time i noticed that root cause of my problems is 'Glyphicons Halflings' font included with bootstrap. I'm trying to render my icon like following

```
<style>
.size24 {
   font-size: 24px;
   background-color: red;
}
</style>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash size24" ></span>
```

but it is actually rendered as 26px height. What is the reason and how it can be fixed? Is this the bug in font? How to make my icon to be exactly 24px*24px?

This appears with bootstrap 3.0.2.

Here is jsfiddle for that case http://jsfiddle.net/U8bLZ/2/ and sample screenshot
[image: sample screenshot]

Enlarged portion to of 3 to 5
[image]

Comment: According to google developer tools, that is 24x24

Comment: Yep, devtools say it 24x24, but visually it is 24x26. I've added border (http://jsfiddle.net/U8bLZ/3/) and enalrged screenshot to see the problem better. The major problem is that it breaks vertical alignment. BTW, you may notice that icons are not correctly vertically aligned in bootstrap samples http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples, they are rather baselined then vertically centered.